# Is there a way to sleep a specific function instead of all script execution in php?

Tags: php, discord

I'm trying to make a php function loop every 5 seconds, but can't have it pause all script execution since other parts of the script need to get stuff done.

```php
    public function status($discord, $status = statusarray, $infinite = true) {
        shuffle($status);
        $activity = $discord->factory(\Discord\Parts\User\Activity::class, [
            'name' => $status[1][0],
            'type' => $status[1][1]
        ]);
        echo "Changed status to \"".$status[1][0]."\" Type of status:".$status[1][1].PHP_EOL;
        $discord->updatePresence($activity);
        if($infinite) {
            sleep(5);
            $this->status($discord, $status, $infinite);
        }
    }
```

This is my code, which chooses a random status every 5 seconds for a discord bot.
That's what $status is, and why it's shuffled.
I have this part of my code on another file for functions specifically on a class.
But, the `if($infinite)` part of the script pauses script execution. Which is the problem.
I've been trying all day to find a way for it to not pause script execution, but haven't found anything helpful, so i'm here once more, waiting for Stack Overflow to do it's thing and give me something i would have never been able to think of.

Comment: "_waiting for Stack Overflow_" - I can guarantee that your idea of calling your function recursively will lead to stack overflow 100%.

Comment: There's nothing in PHP that allows this natively. You might be able to approximate the desired behavior with register_tick_function(), but I wouldn't bother -- just run two scripts, one for the status updater and one for whatever the other actions are.

Comment: What about good old threads?
[https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php#114752]
Could this be an option?

Comment: @crystalAhmet I'll try it out. Thanks!!

Comment: Note "This extension is considered unmaintained and dead" and hasn't been updated since 2016. It requires a ZTS-enabled build of an end-of-life version of PHP, which you'll probably have to compile from source yourself. It's not worth it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Thanks for pointing out. I didn't know that. (My last PHP work dates back some years.)
My apologies.
I'd follow Alex' recommendation not to use this anymore.
[https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php] suggests "parallel". [https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php] Maybe that's worth a shot.